# Can you increase your health by eating candies in Hard Mode?

Tags: candy-box-2

Well I ate around ~50k candies and didn't gain a single health point. Is this a 'hard' feature (like no extra health or it just takes an insanely high amount of candies to gain some) or something?

Only way to increase HP I found so far was heart pendant & plug, but with 480 I honestly think there's no way to kill The Developper.

Comment: Where did you find the pendant?

Comment: @sommerjj The pendant is in the Hole.

Comment: I am now at 672 HP (hard mode) and have not managed to beat the developer yet. Sigh.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When the gamemode is hard, you will not gain health from eating candy. This is the same for both Candy Box and Candy Box 2. The Developper is easier to defeat in hard mode to compensate for this.

Comment: Thanks. That makes sense, kinda feel bad about wasting so much candy, but oh well..